# Empty rows after JTree's non-leaf nodes

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I've created a `JTree` with a `DefaultTreeModel` and some extensions to `DefaultMutableTreeNode`.

When I insert new nodes to the model, (in an Action in the context of the node):

```
MyTreeNode child = new MyTreeNode(some paramaters);
model.insertNodeInto(child, MyTreeNode.this, MyTreeNode.this.getChildCount());
```

I get an empty row after each parent (just empty - no handles or expand icons or anything).

Comment: looks okay - need a sscce for further help

Comment: Empty entries in a `JTree` almost always indicate messed up events going from the model to the tree. So we need more code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had a treeModelListener that expanded the inserted node. I added the listener to JTree's model after creating JTree. The solution was to add the listener to the model before creating Jtree. So that it was called after JTree's listener. It seems jtree.expand(xxx) was messing with jtree if called before jtree was aware of the insert.